# Найти самое большое число из массива

Tags: c, рекурсия

Программа должна найти самое большое число из массива.
После рекурсии параметр `Max` должен вывести 999, но ничего не получается.

В чем может быть ошибка?

```
void TMax(int A[], int N,int *Max)
{
    if(N==0){
       *Max=A[0];
    }
    else
    {
        *Max=A[N];
         if(A[N]>*Max)
        {
            *Max=A[N];
        }
         TMax(A,N-1,*Max);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = { 1, 2, 999, 4, 20};
    int N = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    int k=A[N];

   TMax(A,N,&k);

    printf("%d",k);
}
```

Comment: Для начала, `A[N]` это первый элемент "за массивом". Последний внутри  массива --  это `A[N - 1]`

Comment: Примерно так: `*Max = ((A[N] > *Max) ? A[N] : TMax(A, N++, Max));`

Comment: Но рекурсия тут меньше всего подходит, гораздо проще в цикле это все считать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если уж нужна рекурсия, то надо верно сделать из нее выход. Вы же при ее завершении просто затираете все, что сделали предыдущие вызовы...

```
void TMax(int A[], int N, int *Max)
{
    if(A[N-1] > *Max)
    {
        *Max = A[N-1];
    }
    if (N > 1) TMax(A,N-1,Max);
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = { 1, 2, 999, 4, 20};
    int N = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    int k = A[0];

    TMax(A,N,&k);

    printf("%d",k);
}
```

Еще у вас постоянный выход за границы массива и путаница с индексами - словом, смотрите решение, и что и чем в нем отличается от вашего.

Не забывайте, что в массиве `A[N]` элементы нумеруются от `0` до `N-1`.

Comment: большое спасибо